# Pass js variable in html template to google script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a .gs file which create a html page:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

doGet();
console.log(myvariable);
```

and in that index.html file I'll create a variable in  tag, which I'd like to pass to my .gs file, for further putting it in google spreadsheet.

```
<script>
  var myvariable = 10;
</script>
```

Is there any method that can carry out my need?

Thank you.

Comment: doGet is an endPoint for a webapp and you normally don't return a template without evaluating it first.  The evaluate step is where the server load the data into the template by html is rendered

Answer (score 0):

#### Pass variable to htmltemplate

```
function elfunko() {
  let t = HtmlService.createTemplate('<input type="text" value="<?= globalvariable ?>" />');
  t.globalvariable = "Hello World";
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(t.evaluate(),'title');
}
```

[image]

#### Pass variable back to server from html

This one will pass a variable back to server scripts when you click the button on the dialog you can see the result by looking in elfunko1s execution log.

```
function elfunko() {
  let t = HtmlService.createTemplate('<input type="button" value="<?= globalvariable ?>" onclick="google.script.run.elfunko1({variable:<?= globalvariable ?>})" />');
  t.globalvariable = "Hello World";
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(t.evaluate(),'title');
}

function elfunko1(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
}
```

[image]

```
Cloud logs
Feb 26, 2022, 8:38:00 PM    Debug   {"variable":"Hello World"}
```

[client to server comm](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

[templated html](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)